# Grub boot menu doesn't work - locked NVram

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, grub, zorin

My laptop is running in Win10 and I just installed Zorin OS with dual boot. The installation has gone smoothly.

However, when the laptop boots, it goes directly to Windows.

I jumped to the boot menu screen (press F12 at reboot), the boot menu shows "ubuntu" at first, and "Windows boot manager" second.

When I choose ubuntu, the screen did a quick refresh then show the boot menu again. So the only choice I can select is the windows boot manager. (so I think the laptop reboot actually did try ubutu boot first but failed, then it continue with Windows boot.

I then use the USB boot disk to get in Zorin liveCD mode, perform the grub repair. The results from grub repair shows that there is an error: "Locked-NVram detected".

Tried to google but can't find anything useful.

BIOS boot setting is done as follow:

- Secure boot disabled.
- AHCI enabled.

Any suggestion to make the dual boot work?

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue, m72e lenovo thinkcenter, windows 10 install ok, zorin os 16.3 install ok, when trying to boot, it went to windows.. no grub boot mention options... 
I've read that clearing cmos (battery or jumpers) might help but it didn't for me
fast boot was disabled an all that jazz but nothing.. did you ever get it working? gave up?